# Current sensing circuit

Tags: mosfet, current, schematics, driver

Could you explain how this circuit works? Does it control the resistance of the 'current sensing resistor'?

[image]

Comment: There is no voltage source for any of the resistors, so there is no current.

Comment: What "current sensing resistor"? Where did the circuit come from? Please link to the source of the circuit.

Comment: @analogkid I edited the schematic.

Comment: The diode is in backwards, so there is no current except the diode leakage current.  What is it you are trying to achieve?  Also, which resistor do you think is the "current sensing resistor"?  Where did you get this circuit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming R3 is the sense resistor, a current through it will cause a voltage drop across it of \$I\times100\Omega\$ which is sampled by voltage divider R4 and R5 which is then measured by the ADC.

To change the range of current measured the circuit will switch either R2 or R1 in parallel with R3 to measure 10x or 100x the current. Since R3 remains in the circuit the sense resistance will be it's value in parallel with one of the others, so it loses some accuracy, for the 10\$\Omega\$ resistor the total sense resistance becomes 9.09\$\Omega\$, for the 1\$\Omega\$ it's 0.99\$\Omega\$. The MOSFETs will add a little resistance as well, but it's probably negligible. This inaccuracy may be compensated for in the software.

Comment: thank you very much! why are mosfets used here, not bjt for example?

Comment: @dahaha Because a BJT will have a voltage drop VCE(sat) that would add even more inaccuracy to the reading, a MOSFET can have a much lower voltage drop since it acts like a low resistance when fully on. Example, say you have 1mA through the 100 ohm resistor, that's 0.1V, a 2n3904 has a VCE(sat) of something like 0.2V, so you're ADC is reading 0.3V instead of the 0.1V it should, so quite a bit off. Now replace that with a 2n7000 MOSFET that has an on resistance of 2 Ohms and you would be reading something more like 0.102V, much better.